# Updating ElasticSearch for Gitlab?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, gitlab, redhat

We are running an omnibus version of Gitlab, and need to update to 15.X. However, the instructions state that ElasticSearch must be updated, and that ES is installed separately from GL. From what I am seeing that isn't the case. We did not install ES, instead it appears to have installed with Gitlab as a Ruby gem. Do we still need to update ES manually before the upgrade to GL? Or will it update as a dependency? Any advice here is helpful, we are currently going in circles trying to figure out what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only relevant if you have configured the [Elasticsearch integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/advanced_search/elasticsearch.html#upgrade-to-a-new-elasticsearch-major-version) to enable advanced search with Elasticsearch for your GitLab instance. So first check your settings in the admin panel to see if the integration is configured.

If you are not using the integration, then you don't need to worry about updating it and can skip this step for your GitLab upgrade. The ruby elasticsearch gem is just the client library and will be present in any case, so that seems like a red herring for you here.

If you *do* have the integration configured and *are* using advanced search, then you must update your ES cluster to 7.x for GitLab 15.0 -- Elasticsearch is NOT bundled with GitLab omnibus or source installations; you must install it (and upgrade it) yourself. From [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/advanced_search/elasticsearch.html#install-elasticsearch):

> Elasticsearch is not included in the Omnibus packages or when you install from source. You must install it separately and ensure you select your version.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you very much.